# Appcelerator 4.7 'Bundle identifier is missing.' error

Tags: titanium, bundle, appcelerator, identifier

I'm using Appcelerator Titanium 4.7. When I try to run my app on IOS Device, I'm getting the following error:

```
Bundle identifier is missing
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Titanium 4.7? Can you make a bit clear of what are you using? Like your macos, xcode version, and Titanium SDK?
But, it seems to be a problem with your certificates and Apple developer account. More than that, with your app id!
Open your tiapp.xml file and go to the `<id>` node.
It should start like `<id>` than has your app ID (usually your domain name in reverse) + `</id>`. Suppose your app is called Best App and your domain is www.eren.com. So your app id will be something: com.eren.bestapp. Your id tag on tiapp.xml file will be `<id>com.eren.bestapp</id>`.
Double check it.
If this is correct, than check your App Id on your Apple developer account. Make sure the one in the provisioning profile is the same as your app id on tiapp.xml

Comment: I solved the problem by using my Appcelerator Titanium SDK version. Thx.